# How to get which semester a day belongs to using pandas.Period

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to know an easy way to get which semester a day belongs to while displaying it on following format ('YYYY-SX'); 2018-01-01 -> (2018S1).

I have a date range and is pretty easy to do it for quarters:

```
import pandas as pd

import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)

end = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)

all_days = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D')

all_quarters = []

for day in all_days:
    all_quarters.append(str(pd.Period(day, freq='Q')))
```

However given the docs there is no frequency for semesters:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Period.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

I don't want to necessarily use any specific modules.

Any ideas on how to do it in a clean way?

Comment: You mean "semester" as in school semester period (i.e. Fall = Sep - Dec, Winter = Jan - April, Summer = May - Aug)?

Comment: As a 6 months period. January to June; July to December

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
df['sem']= df.date.dt.year.astype(str) + 'S'+ np.where(df.date.dt.quarter.gt(2),2,1).astype(str)
```

Note: the column `date` needs to be as `datetime` object

**Input**

```
date
0   2019-09-30
1   2019-10-31
2   2019-11-30
3   2019-12-31
4   2020-01-31
5   2020-02-29
6   2020-03-31
7   2020-04-30
8   2020-05-31
9   2020-06-30
```

**Output**

```
          date  sem
0   2019-09-30  2019S2
1   2019-10-31  2019S2
2   2019-11-30  2019S2
3   2019-12-31  2019S2
4   2020-01-31  2020S1
5   2020-02-29  2020S1
6   2020-03-31  2020S1
7   2020-04-30  2020S1
8   2020-05-31  2020S1
9   2020-06-30  2020S1
```

Comment: However I didn't really wanted to create a whole DataFrame for that, but based on your idea I could do something like: 
`all_semesters.append(str(day.year) + 'S' + ['1','2'][day.month >6])` 
Ideally I wanted to use pd.Period as well, but don't think it's going to be possible